# iOS App Store Submission listed as Developer

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store

I am the developer of an APP and will be submitting it to our clients Apple Developer account.

If they have their own developer account is there anyway we can still be listed as the developer in the app store?  The app is based on the ionicFramework / Cordova.

In Config.xml I see author entry, but not exactly sure what that does.

Would appreciate if anyone  who has submitted an app on their clients Apple account could provide some insight on this. I would like to be listed as the developer, but the client wants to use their own developer account, so not sure if that will still be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Apple is very strict about how the developer name appears - it must match the name on the account in the case of an individual account, or the official name of the business in the case of the business account. There is no way to link an app in someone else's account to yours without completely transferring it over.

Comment: Yeah what I figured.  Thanks for the info, much appreciated.